# How to return IGrouping from Linq query when grouping

Tags: c#, .net, windows, linq, group-by

I am adding a bunch of different parts to a `List<>` and some of the part may have the same part number and the same length. If they do have the same partnumber and the same length I need to group those parts for displaying.

When they're grouped I need to show that partnumber and how many of that partnumber with a specific length.

I am needing to know how to group with two differnt properties and return eaigher a typed object with that `List<ICutPart>` and the total of

Below is as far as I could get, I was attempting to return `(IGrouping<int,ICutPart>)sGroup;` but I am getting an error at the return portion of the function body.

How can I return a typed object with `Group{List<ICutPart> Parts, Int Total}`?

```
    public class CutPart : ICutPart
{
    public CutPart() { }
    public CutPart(string name, int compID, int partID, string partNum, decimal length)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.PartID = partID;
        this.PartNumber = partNum;
        this.CompID = compID;
        this.Length = length;
    }
    public CutPart(string name, int compID, int partID, string partNum, decimal width, decimal height)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.CompID = compID;
        this.PartNumber = partNum;
        this.PartID = partID;
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
        this.SF = decimal.Parse(((width / 12) * (height / 12)).ToString(".0000")); //2dp Number;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PartID { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public int CompID { get; set; }
    public decimal Length { get; set; }
    public decimal Width { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public decimal SF { get; set; }
}

public class CutParts : List<ICutPart>
{

    public IGrouping<int, ICutPart> GroupParts()
    {

        var sGroup = from cp in this
                     group cp by cp.Length into g
                     select new
                     {
                         CutParts = g,
                         total = g.Count() 
                     };

        return (IGrouping<int, ICutPart>)sGroup;

    }


    public new void Add(ICutPart item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you want to create a bunch of group objects where each group object has the common `Length` and the bunch of `ICutPart`s that have that length.

In code, it looks something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, ICutPart>> GroupParts()
{
  return this.GroupBy( o => o.Length );
}
```

That probably needs explaining!

---

The `IEnumerable` bit is the collection of group objects - one for each distinct `Length`

Each "group object" in that collection is an `IGrouping<int, ICutPart>`.

This object has a `Key` property, which is the thing you grouped by - `Length` in this case.

It is also a collection as `IGrouping<T>` derives from `IEnumerable<T>` - it is the collection of `ICutPart`s that have that length.

If you call `ToList()` on one of the group objects, you will get a `List<ICutPart>`

---

To make this easier for the caller, you could create a class to hold these values.

If you declared a class like this:

```
public class GroupedByLength
{
  public int Length { get; set; }
  public List<ICutPart> CutParts { get; set; }
}
```

then you could return a collection of these objects:

```
public List<GroupedByLength> GroupParts()
{
  return this
    .GroupBy( o => o.Length )
    .Select( g => new GroupedByLength
      {
        Length = g.Key,
        CutParts = g.ToList(),
      }
    )
    .ToList()
  ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to cast `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int ICutPart>>` to `<IGrouping<int ICutPart>>` `; this will never work. You will have to select an instnace from the IEnumerable<>, perhaps like this:

```
return sGroup.FirstOrDefault();
```